# jOOQ code generation with postgresql does not generate anything

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

When I run jOOQ code generation against my database, it says that there are zero tables, and generates no code.

First, let's see what schemas are in the database. If I log in using the same credentials I am giving to jOOQ, to the same database, and then run `\dn` (as per https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40054/115875) I get this output:

```
List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner
--------+----------
public  | postgres
(1 row)
```

And by running `\dt`, the tables:

```
List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+-------
 public | user | table | me06
(1 row)
```

Just my 1 user table and in one schema, 'public'.

Next, here is my jOOQ configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.9.0.xsd">
<jdbc>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webapi</url>
    <user>webapi</user>
    <password>password</password>
</jdbc>

<generator>
    <name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>
    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <excludes></excludes>
    </database>
    <target>
        <packageName>eden.martin.webapi.models</packageName>
        <directory>C:\users\martin\Code\web-api\app\src\main\java\eden\martin\webapi\models</directory>
    </target>
</generator>
```

However, when I run it, I get this output:

```
INFO: Tables fetched           : 0 (0 included, 0 excluded)
Jan 26, 2017 11:16:07 AM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
```

(Full log is in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/MartinEden/67c1df5f99f61355fc2833b996d49268)

What is going wrong?

Comment: [Your log suggests that you have an `<includes>user</includes>` specification](https://gist.github.com/MartinEden/67c1df5f99f61355fc2833b996d49268#file-jooqgenerate-log-L24), so perhaps, the XML you posted is not the actual XML that you're using?

Comment: ...it's now working, without me changing anything. Ah the heisenbug.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it doesn't make sense, it was working.